# How to create object from Data class? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a

`data class A(){
   fun c(){}
  }` .

I need to create a fake implementation of it for testing, but it says that class must be open. open modifier is incompatible with data class. Any ways to do it?

Comment: Why must you use a fake? What is the real one doing that you want changed in your tests?

Comment: In need of multiple versions of the same class? You are supposed to use an interface then. Mocking becomes easy when you write proper OOP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock final classes update mockito

`testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'`
and then add a folder in your resources folder called mockito-extensions that includes a text file called `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`. Inside there just add

`mock-maker-inline`

That should solve your problem